# Chrome Auto Save Extension - Firefox alternative?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, save, autosave

I've just seen that extension and I pretty much fell in love with. As a guy with minimal css knowledge, I got bored of spamming CTRL + S, alt tab, check browser, alt tab back to IDE and continue development/design loop.

Is there any alternatives to Chrome's Auto Save extension on Firefox? I don't want to leave my years of beloved Firefox for it.

I'm also open for third party tool ideas, if no such extension exists on Firefox. Basically, I want to edit my CSS/Javascript files directly from Firefox Developer Tool to see the results on-the-fly, and most importantly, I want it to get them saved automatically. (or by pressing CTRL + S, since it is something we all used to do for years)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Updater

http://www.cssupdater.com